# Does a python exception generate a software trap/interrupt?

Tags: python, error-handling, operating-system, kernel

Assuing i have some simple error throwing Python code in an interrupter such as:

```
>>> x = 5/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Does this generate a trap at the kernal level or to cause a context switch?
Or is it just handled inside the Python runtime with no real performance hit?

Does this change at all if I wrap my code in an Python exception block?

```
>>> try:
...   x = 5/0
... except :
...   pass
...
>>>
```

Comment: @sj95126 You are talking about the standard implementation "CPython" only or does this apply to all implementations?

Comment: Never mind - I don't feel I gave a thorough enough explanation and have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** No, exceptions don't count as software interrupts, nor do they act as software interrupts/traps.

Interrupts are mainly for OS stuff, whereas the errors in python are actually only coming from `sys.stderr`, and you can write them as well:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write('I am an error!')
```

Output:

```
I am an error!
```

Errors come from `sys.stderr`, they are just in different color, and behave as an error. Also errors are only detected by the interpreter in it's execution.

That means that errors aren't what you think, they are actually just coming from `sys.stderr`.